# All header disappeared from book typeset with octavo package

Tags: header-footer, octavo

All was good for a while, then my headers and page numbers all disappeared. The table of contents, index, and hyper ref links all work, but there is no printing of headers and page numbers. I tried to switch to the memoir class, but again all headers are out!

I use no fancy preamble only

```
\documentclass[crown]{octavo}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
```

And all my chapters are external files that I include with the \input command.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please supply and MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. Also, why have you used the reledmac tag?

Comment: What is MWE? Thanks

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. While I was cleaning up my preamble to post it I discovered that a `\pagestyle{empty}` command was somehow there... So the issue is solved!

Comment: Happy you found a solution! BTW, this is why we encourage making a MWE (*minimal* example) *before* posting: most problems solve themselves while you clean up your own document, so that the question hardly becomes necessary.